# Firebase: How to structure for Multiple WHERE IN Query

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase in my small, side projects for almost a year and totally love it. But couldn't use it for large projects that require complex queries, because of single orderByChild() limitation.

Still thinking of ways to make use of Firebase for the multi where clause scenarios. In one my main project that we developed in PHP, we have a query as below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `masterEvents` 
WHERE causeId IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ) 
AND timeId IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
AND localityID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Above query. filters event that happens in certain localities, happens in specific time blocks and covered under given causes.

- Localities can be 40 in number
- Causes will be around 20
- Time will be 21

**Solution 1:** All 3 filter keys as children

```
{
    "eventIndex": {
        "ev1": {
            "name": "Event 1",
            "location": 2,
            "cause": 3,
            "time": 5,
        },
        "ev2": {
            "name": "Event 2",
            "location": 5,
            "cause": 2,
            "time": 1,
        },
        "ev3": {
            "name": "Event 3",
            "location": 26,
            "cause": 12,
            "time": 18,
        }
    }
}

forEach(location in selectedLocationArray) {
    firebase.database().ref("eventIndex").orderByChild("location").equalTo(location).on("value", snap => {
        // loop through all events and filter them based on selectedCauseArray and selectedTimeArray
    });
}
```

**Solution 2:** 1 Filter key in node path and 2 filter keys as children

```
{
    "eventIndex": {
        "location1": {
            "ev1": {
                "name": "Event 1",
                "cause": 2,
                "time": 1,
            },
            "ev2": {
                "name": "Event 2",
                "cause": 12,
                "time": 18,
            }
        },
        "location2": {
            "ev4": {
                "name": "Event 4",
                "cause": 2,
                "time": 1,
            }
        },
        "location3": {
            "ev8": {
                "name": "Event 9",
                "cause": 2,
                "time": 1,
            },
            "ev9": {
                "name": "Event 9",
                "cause": 12,
                "time": 18,
            }
        }
    }
}

forEach(location in selectedLocationArray) {
    forEach(cause in selectedCauseArray) {
        firebase.database().ref("eventIndex/location" + location).orderByChild("cause").equalTo(cause).on("value", snap => {
            // loop through all events and filter them based on selectedTimeArray
        });
    }
}
```

**Solution 3:** 2 Filter key in node path and 1 filter keys as children

Which of the above will be good efficient solution that I could take? Thanks :-)

PS: Code can be treated as Pseudo code to give an idea of the logic, rather than actual code.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most efficient ways I have found to filter data is by grouping or combining multiple keys together.

For example, in the above structure mentioned in your question, I would add another filed called "_idx_location_cause_time", which is a combination of values in the order - location, cause and time.

```
...
"ev1": {
    "name": "Event 1",
    "location": 2,
    "cause": 3,
    "time": 5,
    "_idx_location_cause_time" : "2_3_5"
},
...
```

Now I can use `orderByChild` query to filter the results. That is,

`dbRef.orderByChild(_idx_location_cause_time).equalTo("2_3_5").once("value", ...);`

This is a general idea of how you can use this to structure your data and filter them accordingly. You can also apply this technique with the techniques you've mentioned in your question to further simply your filtering process.

It is also important that you index it using `.indexOn` in Firebase Rules to improve the performance of the query.

Hope this help!

Comment: Won’t I need multiple composite keys though for this solution? Because you could filter by different combinations

Comment: @AngularM The better solution now is to use Firestore to write advance queries

Comment: Is it easy to move my firebase real-time database to that